# What's the premier .NET Rails-style framework?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I like the Rails approach to web application development quite a bit, but in my current occupation I should like to use .NET technology. What is the premier Rails-style framework in the .NET world? I understand Microsoft has developed [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) as such a framework, but my knowledge of it is totally superficial at this point.

Ease of testing is particularly important to me, I love how you can write testable scenarios for Rails with Cucumber. Testing of Javascript bits should be accounted for as well.

In sum: I'm looking for a .NET alternative that offers the same complete development stack, from end-to-end, you get with Rails :)

Comment: I'm interested in seeing the responses. I favor MVC with linq-to-sql/NHibernate/Entities for the DAL generation, but I haven't seen anything with javascript unit testing built-in.

Comment: I'm interested in the javascript unit testing as well. I'm not sure how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. ASP.NET MVC 3.0 is the framework you are looking for. And it does offer you the complete stack.

For Cucumber style testing you can use [SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/specflow/getting-started.aspx). There are other BDD tools too but SpecFlow is the closest to Cucumber as both are based on Gherkin.

For learning MVC, I would suggest the following tutorials, preferably in the same order:

1. The getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs video on the official ASP.NET MVC website.
2. Next try the Music Store tutorial, once again on the official ASP.NET MVC website. This take things up one notch.
3. You can then google for the nerd dinner tutorial. This is a great tutorial but I am not sure if it has been completely updgraded to ASP.NET MVC 3 or not.
4. http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos: This has a whole lot of videos. You can see The Storefront video series for an example of how to create a complex website using MVC.
5. Lastly, there are some excellent videos (though paid) on tekpub for mastering mvc and building a blog in mvc.

Between these tutorials you will not only just learn the basics, you will also learn Linq2SQL or Entity Framework (ORM), Ninject (Dependency Injection), Moq (Mocking framework), SpecFlow, etc...

In case, you want to try something on your own, you can start with the ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Starter Site
released by Rob Conery (from Tekpub)  on codeplex. Rob is an expert on both ASP.Net MVC and Ruby on Rails and shares the same concerns as you. While this is in MVC 2.0, it should also work with version 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for an elaborate answer, Yasir, and particularly for pointing me to SpecFlow :) Is it possible to test also Javascript with SpecFlow, however, like you can do with Cucumber/Capybara?

Comment: I haven't personally used Capybara or any .NET JavaScript testing framework but you can use browser automation frameworks like WatIn and Selenium. The WatIn website says it supports Ajax website testing. See if that would serve your purpose. WatIn works with IE 6-8 and Firefox 2 and 3.

Answer (score 6):

You answered your own question. ASP.net MVC is what you are looking for. It is easy to create Unit tests for your controllers, routes, etc.

If you want more information on ASP.net MVC, you can visit www.asp.net/mvc. You might also want to follow the following blogs:

http://haacked.com/
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how it stacks (no pun intended) up against Rails? Specifically, how is it wrt. to integration testing (as opposed to unit testing), including of Javascript? I'm interested in where it falls short (it's best to find out about pain points upfront) :)

Comment: @adknuds1 - Isn't asking how a server side language tests javascript like asking how a car drives underwater?  Your javascript unit tests are written in javascript are they not?

Comment: jfar: it's a question of the whole stack. Rails has some integration with Javascript, and there are associated tools to test Javascript bits (e.g., Capybara).